# How do I get started with analyzing XBRL in python?

Tags: python-2.7, xbrl, arelle

How do i get started analyzing XBRL data?

I've heard [python-xbrl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-xbrl) should have some problems, and I'm having difficulties finding documention and examples.

I've heard that [Arelle](https://arelle.org/documentation/api/) is supposed to be what you want to use. But I simple can't figure out how to install it without getting any weird errors.

I've tried:
1) pip install git+https://github.com/Arelle/Arelle.git
Which returns

```
error: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'c:\\users\\bc0655\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-    gkza0x-    build\\.eggs\\3to2-1.1.1-py2.7.egg\\lib3to2\\fixes/*.*'
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\bc0655\appdata\local\temp\pip-gkza0x-build\
```

2) pip install -e git+https://github.com/Arelle/Arelle.git #egg=Arelle

Which returns me:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  \pip\basecommand.py", line 209, in main status = self.run(options, args)
  \pip\commands\install.py", line 287, in run wheel_cache
  \pip\basecommand.py", line 270, in populate_requirement_set wheel_cache=wheel_cache
  \pip\req\req_install.py", line 230, in from_line wheel_cache=wheel_cache, constraint=constraint)
  \pip\req\req_install.py", line 77, in __init__req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  \pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3036, in parse req, = parse_requirements(s)
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

3) Install from zip (would like to avoid this)
Returns same errors as 2).

Should I:

- Try to figure out why my Arelle installations fails (suggestions / help would be appreciated <3 )
- Try another module
- Build my system with python-xbrl

Comment: Have you fixed it? I got the same error and  can tell you that has nothing to do with xbrl as I don't have it. Sounds like a pip bug to me.

Comment: @sorin Sorry to tell you no. I've gone with python-xbrl for now to work around the solution. - let me know if you figure anything out. It could very well be a pip bug.

Answer (score -1):

try this, it worked for me. 
Go to the current path and try using below command

**pip install arelle**